# NLog: how to obtain level of a specific target programatically

Tags: c#, nlog

I currently use NLog and allow admin users to set the level at runtime using a variable as follows:

```xml
<logger name="*" minLevel="${var:myFileLevel}" writeTo="file" />
```

I would like to know the level of this logger at runtime (so I cannot obtain it from the configuration file due to the variable)

I am able to easily obtain the Target as follows:

```cs
Target target= LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("file");
```

but unfortunately there are no relevant methods on the target object to obtain the level.  Is it possible to obtain the logging level at runtime?

Comment: Why don't check `Logger.IsEnabled(logLevel)` or particular `Logger.Is*Enabled` properties? This allows you to be sure in what's configured for any given logger.

Comment: @Dennis  : I tried that but it fails if you have multiple targets configured at different levels.  Accepted solution is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The enabled logging level is configured at the logging rule.

So you could do this:

1. Add a rulename, so you could find the rule easier:

   ```
   <logger name="*" minLevel="${var:myFileLevel}" writeTo="file" ruleName="myrule" />
   ```
2. Find the rule and check the `Levels` property. See [LoggingConfiguration.FindRuleByName Method](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.7.0/html/M_NLog_Config_LoggingConfiguration_FindRuleByName.htm)

   ```cs
   var rule = LogManager.Configuration.FindRuleByName("myrule");
   var levels = rule.Levels;  // enabled levels
   ```

For this case, another option is to read the *myFileLevel* variable value. For that, you need to render it, you could use `LogEventInfo.CreateNullEvent()` for that.

```cs
var myFileLevelLayout = LoggingConfiguration.Variables["myFileLevel"]; // Type SimpleLayout
string value = myFileLevelLayout.Render(LogEventInfo.CreateNullEvent())
```

See 

[LoggingConfiguration.Variables Property](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.7.0/html/P_NLog_Config_LoggingConfiguration_Variables.htm)